# main.WARNING: Memory size allocated for the temporary table is more than 20% of innodb_buffer_pool_size

Tags: error, log

```
Magento 2.4.5-p1
Smartwave Porto theme
```

I have found the following Error in my logs:

```
main.WARNING: Memory size allocated for the temporary table is more than 20% of innodb_buffer_pool_size. Please update innodb_buffer_pool_size or decrease batch size value (which decreases memory usages for the temporary table). Current batch size: 100000; Allocated memory size: 1300000000 bytes; InnoDB buffer pool size: 2147483648 bytes.
```

I googled it and found the following article:

[Magento 2 Please update innodb_buffer_pool_size or decrease batch size value](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/207457/magento-2-please-update-innodb-buffer-pool-size-or-decrease-batch-size-value)

It suggests to update default Batching configuration of catalog_category_product (Category Products) indexer because "Current batch size: 100000" and points to this article here:

https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/indexing/optimization/

I've raised this with our hosting and they responded with:

*On the server end we can increase the 'innodb_buffer_pool_size' value, as per the update of Batching configuration of catalog_category_product, it requires tweaking of the Magento 2 coding, which is a matter that falls outside our scope of expertise.
Currently, 'innodb_buffer_pool_size' is set to 2 GB, upon your request, we can increase it to 4 GB or 8 GB.*

**I am honestly lost. What do I need to do?**

Answer (score 1):

Having your hosting company increase the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` from 2GB to 4GB might be enough to fix the issue.

But if you still want to decrease the batch size, or are having issues even after the hosting company makes their updates, you will need to override the default batch size found in `vendor/magento/module-catalog/etc/di.xml`

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Product\Action\Full">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="batchRowsCount" xsi:type="number">100000</argument>
        <argument name="batchSizeManagement" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\CategoryProductBatchSize</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

You can overwrite the value within one of you modules by adding the following to di.xml (This example changes the batch size from 100000 to 50000):

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Product\Action\Full">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="batchRowsCount" xsi:type="number">50000</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Comment: Thank you. I have asked my hosting to increase it to 4GB as per your suggestion. Would going to 8 GB make any difference at all? In case I decide to decrease the batch size - would I simply replace the code up top in your answer with the one below? Would decreasing the batch size have any unwanted side effects? I am having  many problems (as explained here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/366156/category-products-do-not-load-we-cant-find-products-matching-the-selection/366849#366849 ) & I'm just trying to optimize everything hoping something will make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Magento provide detail for same

Please go this link

https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/indexing/optimization/#exceeding-allocated-memory-size

Not sure 2G is still great as per me but you should get it 4G to resolve the current issue if in future face issue with pool memory size then you can update to 8G but may be too high [Read this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size)

If you want to decrease the batch size two way you can achieve that
Create an extension or set value in ENV file

Thanks